# Как исправить ошибку компиляции кода в InteliJ idea version 17

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Работаю в IneliJ idea и уже не первый раз после закрытия проекта и повторного открытия приходит такая ошибка, хотя ни настройки, ничего не меняю.

```
java: invalid source release 16 with --enable-preview
  (preview language features are only supported for release 17)
```

причем до этого все работало, версия java 17

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте настройки проекта ( `Crtl + Shift + Alt + S` ), скорее всего `Language level` там установлен на `16`, когда `SDK` стоит более высокой версии.

Так же, лучше периодически устанавливать обновления IDE, выбрав `Check fou Updates..` в пункте меню `Help`.

Comment: проблема как в раз в том, что везде стоит 17 версия и там тоже. Такое вот второй раз происходит уже, вчера работал с проектом и все было нормально, сегодня выводит такую ошибку, хотя ни настройки, ничего подобного не менял

Comment: @kzrvv, версия IDEA последняя?

Comment: да, последняя. Нашел старый вариант проекта, новый код весь перекинул туда, все работает. Но что делать с этим, боюсь в такое может произойти еще раз в неудобный момент. Я уже все настройки перерыл.

Comment: @kzrvv, раз проблема решилось со сменой проекта - дело явно в его настройках. Можете попробовать оба проекта на какой-нибудь Яндекс.Диск залить, поколупаюсь.